# Visual Studio Annotating taking longer time

Tags: visual-studio, tfvc

In Visual Studio, while trying to annotate any file is taking more than 1 minute in my machine, while in other's machine it is taking 5-10 seconds. Systems configurations are same. Any setting that I am missing?

Comment: TFVC? Is the workspace configured as Local or Server?

Comment: @jessehouwing : it was local. have changed to server and that worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on below page:

https://johnlnelson.com/2014/09/08/tfs-2012-errors-tf400030-and-tf400017-concurrent-access-to-local-workspaces/

Team Explorer-> Source Control Explorer - > Select 'Workspaces' From Workspace Dropdown -> Select your workspace and Edit -> Advanced -> Change Location to 'Server' from 'Local' -> OK

One more solution could be removing multiple workspaces.